# Issues with array[i].match and array[i].substring

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanna use `array[i].match` and `array[i].substring` but this presents a problem to me.

If I wanna output this matches I get a blank page.

**JavaScript**

```
var List = ["example1", "example2", "example3", "example21", "example12"];
var array = [];

for (var i = 0; i < List.length; i++) {
  Entry = List[i];
  var counts = Entry.match(/1/g).length;

  //var n = Entry.search("example1");

  if (counts >= 1) {
    array.push(Entry);
  }

}

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var Eintrag = document.createElement("div");
  Eintrag.style.background = "DodgerBlue";
  Eintrag.style.width = "50px";
  Eintrag.style.height = "10px";
  Eintrag.style.marginLeft = "1%";
  Eintrag.style.marginRight = "1%";
  Eintrag.style.border = "thin solid red";
  CallOutputBox.appendChild(Eintrag);
}
```

With `array[i].search` it works fine.

Comment: This code makes no sense. What are you tying to accomplish here ? If you want to iterate over `List` then, you should assign `Entry = List[i]` (and declare `var Entry` before your loop. Also please indent your code!

Comment: Sorry, I´ve changed the code, I hope this time it´s better. I wan´t to fill the page based on the array. the result should be two created elements based on example1 and example12.

Comment: `counts` is not used at all after assignment?

Comment: it´s used with match this is the working version with search, better I change it to matched. Thank you for your comment!

Comment: My problem here is that the creation of the elements works just fine, when I use .search but if I wanna use .match or .substring they don´t show up. I don´t understand the reason.

Comment: Now there should be 3 Elements, one for example1, example21 and example11

Comment: Do you want all the strings with '1' in it?

Comment: Thank you Peter Leger for your edit. I want all the strings with "1" and I also want to no how often "1" appears. In other words, I want to be able to find all with "1" and then I want just all with for example two "1". This is just an example.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not working because you're assuming there will be an array. If there's no match, there's no array. So you need to check to see if `counts` exists and then check the length.

[DOCS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

An Array containing the entire match result and any parentheses-captured matched results; `null if there were no matches`.

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/juxinudowi/edit?js,console,output)

```
var counts = Entry.match(/1/g);

if (counts && counts.length >= 1) {
   // do stuff
}
```